# "EntityType has no key defined" exception although key is defined with HasKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Using EF 5 (reverse engineered code first), my model was working fine until it suddenly stopped.

> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ProjectsDate' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ProjectsRisk' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

I define a key using fluent API rather than attributes, here is my ProjectsDates classes.

> ```
> public partial class ProjectsDate
> {
>     public string OSProjectCode { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> TargetStart { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateOriginal { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateChangeControl { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateActual { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> GoLiveAgreed { get; set; }
>     public Nullable<System.DateTime> GoLiveActual { get; set; }
>     public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
> }
> ```

```
public class ProjectsDateMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectsDate>
{
    public ProjectsDateMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.OSProjectCode);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.OSProjectCode)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("ProjectsDates");
        this.Property(t => t.OSProjectCode).HasColumnName("OSProjectCode");
        this.Property(t => t.TargetStart).HasColumnName("TargetStart");
        this.Property(t => t.EndDateOriginal).HasColumnName("EndDateOriginal");
        this.Property(t => t.EndDateChangeControl).HasColumnName("EndDateChangeControl");
        this.Property(t => t.EndDateActual).HasColumnName("EndDateActual");
        this.Property(t => t.GoLiveAgreed).HasColumnName("GoLiveAgreed");
        this.Property(t => t.GoLiveActual).HasColumnName("GoLiveActual");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Project)
            .WithOptional(t => t.ProjectsDate);

    }
}
```

Why doesn't EF see my fluent API mapping?

Comment: Maybe you didn't add an instance of `ProjectsDateMap` to `modelBuilder.Configurations` in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Just double checked, it is in OnModelCreating, cheers anyway

Comment: What a pity, it had been such a simple explanation and fix :) Did you check in the debugger if the `HasKey` line is actually passed?

Comment: Aye, I was ready to be embarrassed but happy it was working aha ;p. If I breakpoint the modelmap class should it be hit? I can't seem to hit the `OnModelCreating` or `HasKey`

Comment: Yes, it should hit the line when you use a context for the first time after application start. Is this a project converted from db-first or model-first? Is it possible that you have an edmx somewhere still in the project or a connection string that contains metadata sections? EF would not see it as Code-First then and never call `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: Hmm, I used EF Power Tools to reverse engineer from a database.

Comment: Also, to throw a curve ball in, I recreated another context I also have, and this has made this context work and hit the breakpoints. Would this mean EF failed silently loading the first context and didn't bother getting to the second?

Comment: Hm, don't understand exactly. Do you mean that in a second `using (var ctx = new MyContext())` `OnModelCreating` is called but not on the first one? You can btw edit your question to put new infos in there (use "edit" link below your question). It's a better place then a long comment thread. (I've changed your question title btw. "Entity Framework" wasn't that good as a meaningful title :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason (probably a bug), FluentAPI needs the key to be defined in a convention way - that is - ClassName + Id, or in your case:

```
ProjectsDateId
```

This way the metadata created by EF can acknowledge the fact it is related.
Very annoying but...

Comment: Does not work.  I have an entity named Offer, and I set the key to be named OfferID, but EF still complains no key is defined.  The only thing that works is using [Key,ForeignKey("Offer")] on the property, and then the property can be named anything I want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a global binding or individual binding in `OnModelCreating`
(`DbModelBuilder modelBuilder`).

So it would look something like this in your context file:

```
public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // global
    modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    // individual
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectsDateMap());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by re-running the reverse engineer code first from EF power tools. Seemed to work from there out, this seems to be a general problem that kicks up when your models aren't configured right. It's a shame it seems so general and just kicks up misleading errors.